# Cant read data from plist

Tags: ios4, plist

I am having trouble with reading data from my plist file. What is the correct way of extracting the values in a string? And lets say I have 2 items, how do I get both? Below will be the image on the plist. [image: EventAddress.plist]

And below is the source code for the plist. I read somewhere that there could be a difference with Xcode 3 and Xcode 4.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Array</key>
    <array>
        <string>value 1</string>
        <string>value 2</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do reply about this still. But I managed to find a code that got it working for me already. The codes are below. Thanks peylow for your effort.

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"EventAddress" ofType:@"plist"]; 
    NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    NSArray* allmyKeys = [myDictionary  allValues];
    NSLog(@"%@", allmyKeys);
    NSLog(@"%@", [[allmyKeys objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0]);
```

The last 2 NSLog is used to see if my plist does return an array of values and to find out the value of only 1 of them. And thanks a lot about the debugger, after looking at it for almost 3 days straight, I also realized my problem. The damn array isn't the normal one dimension, its TWO DIMENSION. Thats why I used objectAtIndex twice.

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this !!! I was breaking my head on this. I'm sure this has to do with plist files being created in xcode 4.0.

Comment: But I heard somewhere that this method maybe working, but it is not the ideal way of doing it. Don't stop looking for correct answers or ways to do this. But I am glad that this method helped you :)

Answer (score 3):

First you need to get the path for the plist file resource in your application bundle:

```
NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" 
                                                      ofType:@"plist"];
```

Given this path you can load the plist file into memory. This is quite simple since your root node of the plist file is an array:

```
NSArray* plist = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

More often the root node in your plist is a dictionary, dictionary has an equivalent convenience method for loading plists. If the root node is unknown then you should sue the `NSPropertyListSerialization` class, a bit more work but much more flexible.

The contents in memory of a plist will always be instances of the *property value* classes, use them as you would with any instances of them:

- `NSData`
- `NSString`
- `NSArray`
- `NSDictionary`
- `NSDate`
- `NSNumber`

Comment: Alright, thanks for your reply. So if I wanted the value "value 1" do I need to do `NSString *v1 = [plist objectAtIndex:0];`??

Comment: when I did the nsarray *plist, I get a non-initialized array 0x0 when I run the debugger... how do I overcome this?

Comment: @Melvin Lay - If you get `nil` *(0x0)* that means you could not open the plist. Have you made sure you use the correct filename, and that it is copied into the application bundle? File names on iOS are case sensitive.

Comment: The file name is EventAddress.plist so my `pathForResource:@"EventAddress"` right?

Comment: @Melvin Lai - Should be correct, is the path set to something else than `nil`?

Comment: @MelvinLai let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2838/discussion-between-peylow-and-melvin-lai)