# method not getting value from plist

Tags: iphone, ios5, theos

For some reason I'm not getting the value from my plist and I'm not sure why here is the plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CachedColors</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.Halfbrick.Fruit</key>
        <string>0.00000,0.00000,0.00000</string>
        <key>com.amazon.Amazon</key>
        <string>0.00000,0.00000,0.00000</string>
        <key>com.apple.AdSheetPhone</key>
        <string>0.00000,0.00000,0.00000</string>
        <key>com.apple.AppStore</key>
        <string>0.28824,0.37059,0.48235</string>
    <key>default</key>
    <true/>
    <key>gradient</key>
    <false/>
    <key>opaque</key>
    <true/>
    <key>showedMessage</key>
    <true/>
    <key>translucent</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

and my method is:

```
SBApplication *frontApp = [(SpringBoard*)[UIApplication sharedApplication] _accessibilityFrontMostApplication];
NSString *frontAppBundleID = [frontApp displayIdentifier];
NSDictionary *statusBarCachedColors = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/cc.tweak.statuscolor.plist"];
NSString *colorString = (NSString*)[statusBarCachedColors objectForKey:frontAppBundleID];
NSArray *components = [colorString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
UIColor *tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:[[components objectAtIndex:0] floatValue] green:[[components objectAtIndex:1] floatValue] blue:[[components objectAtIndex:2] floatValue] alpha:1];
```

whats supposed to happen is, my method would get the Display ID for the current application, then get the value for the app from the plist, then split the value string and make a UIColor from the array. so if I opened the AppStore, it would search the plist and return "0.28824,0.37059,0.48235" and make that into the color, but it doesn't seem to return anything, I've tested the displayIdentifier and that is correct it does display the correct app display id, i just don't know why it isn't getting a value

Comment: just print the array that its got value or not using this line.. NSLog(@"\n Array Color %@", components);

Comment: I checked my "colorString" and that is empty, before it's separated it's empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the item **CachedColors**.

```
NSString *colorString = (NSString*)[[statusBarCachedColors objectForKey:@"CachedColors"] objectForKey:frontAppBundleID];
```

Comment: Something so obvious had me so stumped lol, that fixed it, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

use this bellow code may be it work..

Get value from plist like bellow...

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PlistFileName" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray  *arrPList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

after use your code and try with bellow logic..

```
float clrRed = [[components objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
float clrGreen = [[components objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
float clrBlue = [[components objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];

UIColor *tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:clrRed green:clrGreen blue:clrBlue floatValue] alpha:1];
```

Comment: It's not that it isn't separating the string correctly, it's not getting the string from the plist at all

Comment: oh yes i know ok now get the value in array and then use that value directly, without convert in floatValue.. understand ??

Comment: NSBundle won't work because I'm developing for jailbroken devices

Comment: yes yes mate but now just get the data in array like i define above and then use it without convert it in float try and letr me know if any problem you will get... :)

Comment: ‘NSMutableArray’ may not respond to ‘-objectForKey:’

thats the error I'm getting using your code

Comment: but you Nslog the array which get from plist??

Comment: @iGamers you get the value and data from plist??? and also print that value using NSLog and then let me know .. what you got...

Comment: the console says Array Color (null)

Comment: oh then color string is also null dude .. do something with plist dude.. and get data from that

Comment: i just don't know why it isn't getting the value from the plist, idk what is wrong with it

Comment: @iGamers see this answer also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174281/cant-read-data-from-plist may you get some idea from that so..

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                      @"<plist file name>" ofType:@"plist"];

NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Try this hope it will work.

Comment: I'm creating for a jail broken environment so [NSBundle mainBundle] won't work I don't think